# Python: string to list with user defined splits

Tags: string, list, python-2.7

I know that in Python there's the possibility of converting a given string into a list:

```
>>> h='ghilmnoPqzH'
>>> list(h)
['g', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'P', 'q', 'z', 'H']
```

But how can I split the list into given intervals? I.e., given the above string `h` if I set a parameter `s=4` I should get

```
['ghi', 'lmn', 'oPq', 'zH']
```

This question is different from [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) because, if I use that function I get the following error:

`<generator object chunks at 0x0296A030>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Comment: Not really. I have tried to apply that function and I get the error `<generator object chunks at 0x0296A030>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> interval = 3
>>> s = 'ghilmnoPqzH'
>>> [s[start:start + interval] for start in range(0, len(s), interval)]
['ghi', 'lmn', 'oPq', 'zH']
```